# Am getting gibberish when i run code on laravel query

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel and I am practicing with laravel 7 by following an online tutorial featuring the query builder. Everything worked fine, until I got to the code to join the 2 table. Products and Users.

Initially I received a complaint with regards to the memory. I googled and found a solution, which I implemented on my php.ini file. Then, after running the script again, I got a page full of gibberish which I cannot make sense of.
Here is my controller where I am running the query:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Profile extends Controller
{
function index(){

   
        $data = DB::table('users')->join('products','users.id','products.user_id');
     
        print_r($data);
```

And here is my router

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('profile','Profile@index');
```

---

This is the response I received when I visited the profile page.

```
Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder Object ( [connection] => Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection Object ( [pdo:protected] => Closure Object ( [static] => Array ( [config] => Array ( [driver] => mysql [host] => 127.0.0.1 [port] => 3306 [database] => lara7 [username] => root [password] => godly123 [unix_socket] => [charset] => utf8mb4 [collation] => utf8mb4_unicode_ci [prefix] => [prefix_indexes] => 1 [strict] => 1 [engine] => [options] => Array ( ) [name] => mysql ) ) [this] => Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory Object ( [container:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object ( [basePath:protected] => C:\newxampp\htdocs\lara7 [hasBeenBootstrapped:protected] => 1 [booted:protected] => 1 [bootingCallbacks:protected] => Array ( [0] => Closure Object ( [static] => Array ( [instance] => Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider Object ( [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* ) ) [this] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* ) ) [bootedCallbacks:protected] => Array ( [0] => Closure Object ( [this] => App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider Object ( [namespace:protected] => App\Http\Controllers [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* ) ) ) [terminatingCallbacks:protected] => Array ( ) [serviceProviders:protected] => Array ( [0] => Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider Object ( [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* ) [1] => Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider Object ( [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* ) [2] => Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider Object ( [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* ) [3] => Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider Object ( [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* ) [4] => Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider Object ( [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* ) [5] => Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider Object ( [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* ) [6] => Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider Object ( [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* ) [7] => Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider Object ( [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* ) [8] => Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FormRequestServiceProvider Object ( [app:protected] => Illuminate\Foundation\Application Object *RECURSION* ) [9] =>
```

etc etc

Comment: Please append `->get();` after `DB::table('users')->join('products','users.id','products.user_id')` to see if it works.

Comment: The above suggestion is most likely the fix. Its returning an instance of query builder (this is what allows you to chain more conditions onto it). In order to actually execute a query, you need to chain a method that does so (like `get` or `first`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please append `->get();` after `DB::table('users')->join('products','users.id','products.user_id')`.

```php
DB::table('users')->join('products','users.id','products.user_id')->get();
```

This is happening because its returning an instance of query builder (this is what allows you to chain more conditions onto it). In order to actually execute a query, you need to chain a method that does so (like `get()` or `first()`)